# C++ finding something in vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have an vector like this:

```
struct RIFT_MONSTER_SPAWN
{
    DWORD dwWorldId;
    D3DXVECTOR3 vPos;
};

vector<RIFT_MONSTER_SPAWN> vecMSpawn;
```

As you can see it will hold 2 values `dwWorldId` and `D3DXVECTOR3 vPos;`
`vPos` will hold `x,y,z` value.

Now what I want to do is looping true the vector and if the `worldId` matches the `worldId` that is beeing passed. It should return the `vPos` that is releated to the `worldId`.

If have use `std::find find_all` and `count`.
But it always returns the error
binary == no operator found which takes a left hand operator of type

So I am an bit stuck on this. Any help would be appreciated.

With kind regards.

Here is the code that is giving me problems

```
void CRiftMatch::GetMoverSpawnPoints(dwWorldId)
{
    std::vector<RIFT_MONSTER_SPAWN> vecSpawn = CRiftMng::GetInstance()->m_vecMSpawnPoint;
    std::vector<RIFT_MONSTER_SPAWN>::iterator it = std::find(vecSpawn.begin(), vecSpawn.end(), dwWorldId);
    OUTPUTDEBUGSTRING("\n GetMoverSpawn %d", *it);
}
```

m_vecMSpawnPoint is defined in .h file as

```
vector<RIFT_MONSTER_SPAWN> m_vecMSpawnPoint;
```

Also to fill it i am using this code

```
while (Lua.TableLoop(-2))
        {
            RIFT_MONSTER_SPAWN rSpawnPoint;
            rSpawnPoint.dwWorldId = static_cast<int>(CScript::GetDefineNum(Lua.GetFieldToString(-1, "dwWorldId")));
            rSpawnPoint.vPos.x = static_cast<float>(Lua.GetFieldToNumber(-1, "x"));
            rSpawnPoint.vPos.y = static_cast<float>(Lua.GetFieldToNumber(-1, "y"));
            rSpawnPoint.vPos.z = static_cast<float>(Lua.GetFieldToNumber(-1, "z"));

            m_vecMSpawnPoint.push_back(rSpawnPoint);
            Lua.Pop(1);
        }
```

Comment: That is not a vector, that is a structure, even a D3DXVECTOR3 is a structure. You should post the code that is causing the error.

Comment: Use std:find_if and provide your own comparisons function.

Comment: void CRiftMatch::GetMoverSpawnPoints(dwWorldId)
{
 std::vector<RIFT_MONSTER_SPAWN> vecSpawn = CRiftMng::GetInstance()->m_vecMSpawnPoint;
 std::vector<RIFT_MONSTER_SPAWN>::iterator it = std::find(vecSpawn.begin(), vecSpawn.end(), dwWorldId);
 OUTPUTDEBUGSTRING("\n GetMoverSpawn %d", *it);
}

Comment: @RawN done as you asked.

Comment: For the love of the universe stop using all caps names.

Answer (score 2):

You have to modify your struct to be able compare values during find:

```
struct RIFT_MONSTER_SPAWN
{
    DWORD dwWorldId;
    D3DXVECTOR3 vPos;

    bool operator () ( const RIFT_MONSTER_SPAWN & m ) const
    {
        return m.dwWorldId == dwWorldId;
    }
};

RIFT_MONSTER_SPAWN monsterToFind;
monsterToFind.dwWorldId = dwWorldId;

it = std::find_if( vecSpawn.begin(), vecSpawn.end(), monsterToFind);
```

---

Maybe just a type, but in your code, you have

```
void CRiftMatch::GetMoverSpawnPoints(dwWorldId)
```

but it should be

```
void CRiftMatch::GetMoverSpawnPoints(DWORD dwWorldId)
```

Comment: It isn't even necessary to modify the struct. In fact, it seems turn the type into a predicate for itself.

Comment: Thank you. But i dont quite understand it. For example how to output the vPos when dwWorldId has been found?

I am an rookie at c++ so that is why i am trying to understand how it works.

Comment: You find the entire struct. From that, you can get vPos and dwWorldId

Answer (score 2):

You could pass a predicate (which can be a lambda) to [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) so code

```
  auto it = std::find_if(vecSpawn.begin(), vecSpawn.end(),
                         [&] (const struct RIFT_MONSTER_SPAWN& sp) 
                            {return sp.dxWorldId == dwWorldIt;});
```

But in such a case I would simply use a `for` loop (because I find that more readable):

```
  int ix=0;
  for (auto&sp : vecSpawn) {
     if (sp.dxWorldId == dwWorldIt) 
        return vecSpawn.begin() + ix;
     ix++;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

With [range/v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/), you may simply do

```
auto it = ranges::find(vecSpawn, dwWorldIt, &RIFT_MONSTER_SPAWN::dxWorldId);
```

else you have to use more verbose

```
auto it = std::find_if(vecSpawn.begin(), vecSpawn.end(),
                       [&](const RIFT_MONSTER_SPAWN& e) {
                           return e.dxWorldId == dwWorldIt;
                       });
```

Comment: The more verbose variant is exactly my answer.